# Remote connection problem

Tags: 10.04, networking, mysql, putty

Hello I have ubuntu 10.04 installed with mysql on it and I have a problem with remote connection.

When I connect through putty it works but sometimes it looks like it hangs for example when I execute the command `ln --help`.

Also with MySQL connection When I execute a simple query like show processlist; it works, but for example select * from table not always, if the table doesn't have many rows it works but if it has let's say more than 20 the query looks like it keeps working and never ends.

It's connected but I can't do many things remotely.

Added:
I connect using putty from other windows pc, server is not overloaded.
when i work at the same time directly on ubuntu i can do everything. Remotely not.

Answer (score 1):

At first, why you are using PuTTY in Ubuntu, when you can use terminal and `ssh`?

Most probably you have buggy internet connection or your server is seriously overloaded. PuTTY disconnects ssh immediately if there is short break in connection. For example OpenSSH waits until timeout.

If you can (for example using local console or similar), try seeing server load (try `top`) and error messages (`dmesg`).